# Concatenate Vectors in Java

Tags: java, vector, merge

Is there any easy and quick way to merge 2 java vectors to 1?

For example if I have:

```
  Vector<Object> Va = (Vector<Object>)Return_Vector_with_Objs();
  Vector<Object> Vb = (Vector<Object>)Return_Vector_with_Objs();

  Vector<Object> Vmerge_a_b = function_that_takes_a_b_merges(Va,Vb);
```

Is there any function like function_that_takes_a_b_merges or easy way to merge these 2 vectors ?

I don't want to do it with loops and add() etc. I am asking if there is a quicker way.

EDIT: I also want the repeated objects to be ruled out.

Comment: I'd read up on vector addition firstly: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/u3l1b.cfm

Comment: Depends on your definition of _merging_. You can use `Vector#addAll`, a `TreeSet` if you want orderer unrepeated elements, an `ArrayList` or even a `LinkedList`. What's merging for you? the elements of vector1 followed by the elements of vector2?.

Comment: That is a good comment. I actually want a new vector with all the unrepeated objects. I don't care about ordering at all (but just for curiosity how could it be ordered?!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip two Java Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists)

Answer (score 6):

Sure!

```
static Vector<Object> function_that_takes_a_b_merges(Vector<Object> Va, Vector<Object> Vb) {
  Vector<Object> merge = new Vector<Object>();
  merge.addAll(Va);
  merge.addAll(Vb);
  return merge;
}
```

It’s important to start with a new vector, otherwise you will change `Va` if you call `Va.addAll()`.

Comment: Why wouldn't just saying Va.addAll(Vb) in the first place be a good idea? Would that not work?

Comment: @BreadicalMD “It’s important to start with a new vector, otherwise you will change `Va` if you call `Va.addAll()`.”

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(va);
set.addAll(vb);
Vector<String> merged = new Vector<>(set);
```

**Note:**`Vector` is quite an old `Collection` now which has the overhead of synchronized methods which has a performance cost. `ArrayList` could be used instead and also has the `addAll` method from the `List` interface contract. If you *do* require a synchronized `Collection`, you can use [Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) to synchronize your original `List`.

Comment: I actually wanted to have a synchronized collection that's why I used it. So there will be repeated object in mergedVector with this method?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like a `HashSet` in that case.

Comment: Vector is still actual for such old but popular libraries as JSCH, for lsEntry class, for example.