# How to zip two Java Lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 Lists:

```
List<String> subjectArr = Arrays.asList<String>("aa", "bb", "cc");
List<Long> numArr = Arrays.asList<Long>(2L, 6L, 4L);
```

How do I create new `List` and zip two Lists into it?

```
List<?> subjectNumArr = zip(subjectArr, numArr);
// subjectNumArr == [{'aa',2},{'bb',6},{'cc',4}]
```

Comment: Perhaps, a map should be more usefeul for the composite collection

Comment: you will need to create a custom object which can be used for create such a list

Answer (score 48):

Here's Java-8 solution using the `Pair` class (like in @ZhekaKozlov answer):

```
public static <A, B> List<Pair<A, B>> zipJava8(List<A> as, List<B> bs) {
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(as.size(), bs.size()))
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(as.get(i), bs.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In Java 9 onwards you can use `Map.entry()`:

```
    public static <A, B> List<Map.Entry<A, B>> zipJava9(List<A> as, List<B> bs) {
        return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(as.size(), bs.size()))
                .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(as.get(i), bs.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Note: If the lists don't provide efficient random access (eg:linked list), each of those get() will be O(n) instead of O(1)

Comment: I suppose you should rename `zipJava8` as `zipJava9` in your Java 9 example.

Answer (score 14):

As per [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040802/google-guava-zip-two-lists), you can use Guava (>= 21.0) to do this:

```
List<String> subjectArr = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc");
List<Long> numArr = Arrays.asList(2L, 6L, 4L);
List<Pair> pairs = Streams.zip(subjectArr.stream(), numArr.stream(), Pair::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the guava method is annotated as `@Beta`, though what that means in practice is up to interpretation, the method has not changed since version 21.0.

Comment: or [jool](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), looks like this: `Seq.of("a","b", "c").zip(Seq.of(3,2,1))`

Comment: It's worth noting that `Streams.zip` is marked as `@Beta`, which may restrict its use in certain workpaces.

Answer (score 12):

To get an `Iterator<C>` from an `Iterator<A>`, an `Iterator<B>`, and a `BiFunction<A, B, C>`:

```java
public static <A, B, C> Iterator<C> map(Iterator<A> a, Iterator<B> b, BiFunction<A, B, C> f) {
    return new Iterator<C>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return a.hasNext() && b.hasNext(); // This uses the shorter of the two `Iterator`s.
        }

        public C next() {
            return f.apply(a.next(), b.next());
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use an ArrayList of `Map.Entry<String, Long>`, checking that both arraylists have equal size (as it seems to be your requirement), like that:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Long>> subjectNumArr = new ArrayList<>(numArr.size());
if (subjectArr.size() == numArr.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < subjectArr.size(); ++i) {
        subjectNumArr.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>(subjectArr.get(i), numArr.get(i));
    }   
}
```

That's all the code you need!

Then, to iterate over the results, use something like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : subjectNumArr) {
    String key = entry.getKey(); 
    Long value = entry.getValue();
}
```

or, you can simply get the pair at position i (keeping insertion order), by:

```
Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = subjectNumArr.get(i);
```

This can also hold duplicate entries, unlike the Map solution that I initially suggested, without requiring to define your own (Pair) class.

Answer (score 7):

The operation you want is called [zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115563/what-is-zip-functional-programming).

You need to implement a method `zip`:

```
public static <A, B> List<Pair<A, B>> zip(List<A> as, List<B> bs) {
  Iterator<A> it1 = as.iterator();
  Iterator<B> it2 = bs.iterator();
  List<Map.Entry<A, B>> result = new ArrayList<>();
  while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
    result.add(Map.entry(it1.next(), it2.next()));
  }
  return result;
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
zip(subjectArr, numArr);
```

Comment: A static factory method `makePair<A,B>(A left, B right)` instead of the constructor in Pair would make this line possible: `result.add(Pair.makePair(it1.next(), it2.next()));` (no need to repeat the types)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: How can I aceess the first element of each tuple after this implementation?

Comment: @Silvermoon `for (Pair<A, B> pair : list) { pair.left(); }` ?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Thanks, also if I want to return a tuple of floats and not as strings, how should the toString method be modified? I tried returning strings like you suggested and then convert it back to float but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with vefthym however if you have to do using list then create a class like below -:

```
class DirtyCoding{
   String subject;
   int numbr;
}
```

Then iterate over the your list, create object of `DirtyCoding`, populate it and add then add it to `List<DirtyCoding>`.

Answer (score 2):

My ideas:

- **Define a class** for your pairs. This makes your code *extendable* (i.e. if you want to add a third field).
- Define your Lists with the convinient method **`Arrays.asList`**. It is *easy to understand*, *short* and automatically generates generic collections.
- Use **superclasses or interfaces as variable types**. I used `List` in the example, maybe `Collection` would be even better. Only declare variables as `ArrayList` if you need the list to be so specific. That will give you the possibility to use other implementations, without having to change much code.

I would create `Pair` objects like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Pair {
    String subject;
    Long num;
}

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> subjectArr = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc");
        List<Long> numArr = Arrays.asList(2l,6l,4l);

        // create result list
        List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

        // determine result size
        int length = Math.min(subjectArr.size(), numArr.size());

        // create pairs
        for (int position = 0; position < length; position++) {
            Pair pair = new Pair();
            pair.subject = subjectArr.get(position);
            pair.num = numArr.get(position);
            pairs.add(pair);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the answers from [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)
to zip and apply a function at the same time

e.g. Using a zipped Stream:

```
<A,B,C>  Stream<C> zipped(List<A> lista, List<B> listb, BiFunction<A,B,C> zipper){
     int shortestLength = Math.min(lista.size(),listb.size());
     return IntStream.range(0,shortestLength).mapToObject( i -> {
          return zipper.apply(lista.get(i), listb.get(i));
     });        
}
```

for which you may also use Guava's Streams.zip()

Answer (score 1):

You should create an ArrayList of List:

```
ArrayList<List> subjectNumArr = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iter = subjectArr.iterator();
int count=0;
while(iter.hasNext()){
    subjectNumArr.add(Arrays.asList(iter.next(),numArr.get[count++]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**In Java 8:** 
You can do this in one line using Stream and Collectors class.

**In Java 7/6/5:**

```
List list = new ArrayList();

        if(subjectArr.size() == numArr.size())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < subjectArr.size(); i++) { // Loop through every subject/name
                list.add(subjectArr.get(i) + " " + numArr.get(i)); // Concat the two, and add it
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would you do this in Java8?