# How the two list traversal output

Tags: java

```
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("1");
    list1.add("2");
    list1.add("3");
    list1.add("4");
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("5");
    list2.add("6");
    list2.add("7");
    list2.add("8");
```

//How the two list traversal output 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what would you want to happen if the lists had different lengths?

Comment: Possible answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists

Comment: list1 output  value after list2 output value

Comment: if the two lists have the same length always, so you can use for-loop and output the value of first list then the second one.

Comment: if the two lists have the same length always。
      for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
   System.out.println(list1.get(i)); 
   System.out.println(list2.get(i)); 
  } //  if the two list length not same。how to write?

Comment: @kero99 That depends on *your* requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("1");
    list1.add("2");
    list1.add("3");
    list1.add("4");
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("5");
    list2.add("6");
    list2.add("7");
    list2.add("8");
    list2.add("9");
    list2.add("10");
    int n = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        if(list1.size()> i){
            System.out.println(list1.get(i));
        } 
        if(list2.size()> i){
            System.out.println(list2.get(i)); 
        }
    }
```