# Iterate and validate two lists of Objects in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 lists:

- List1: `Object1 (Empno1, Empname1,Salary1)`
- List2: `Object2(Empno2, Empname2,Salary2) Object3(Empno3, Empname3,Salary3)`

Given the size of List1 is not same as List2.

I want to iterate over the List1 and List2, if the `Empno` in List1 object is same as `Empno` of List2 Object then we have to validate `Empname` in List1 object is same as `Empname` of List2 Object

here is the code using old java:

```
boolean flag=false;

  for(Object1 obj1:list1) {

    for(Object2 obj2:list2) {

      if(obj1.getEmpno()==obj2.getEmpno()) {

         if(obj1.getEmpname().equals(obj2. getEmpname())){

          flag=true;

      }

     }

   }

}
```

Which is the best way to implement this with java8

Comment: Actual naming convention used in the code would have been good to use to make the question much clear. What did you try further?

Comment: You must explore the possibility of overriding equals method, for this kind of requirements.

Comment: @Naman I want to make one flag true if all the conditions satisfies

Comment: What is the relation between `Object1` and `Object2` ? Those have the same attribute but not the same class.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a "zip" method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution to find if there is one exact object in one another list is:

```
boolean b = list1.parallelStream().anyMatch(s -> list2.contains(s));
```

as @Kris mentioned too, it needs the equal method to be implemented for your Object class to be overridden like it:

```
class Object1 {
    int empNo;
    String empName;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Object2)obj).empNo == this.empNo && 
                ((Object2)obj).empName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.empName);
    }

    @Override        
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + Integer.valueOf(empNo).hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + this.empName.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The 17 31 hash code idea is from Effective Java book and for further information about it, follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/299748/2137378

Comment: You can use any method for comparing, it is not necessary to override equals and use contains

Comment: Please also override `hashCode`, else someone will copy this code and learn a bad lesson.

Comment: this is so wrong: you'll get `ClassCastException` every time you call `equals` with any other parameter type than `Object2`. Also you are accessing `Object2` fields directly without getters

Comment: @Adrian, yeah the method depends on these two types. But you are wrong. It does not mean if it is strongly dependent on a class, it can not be executed correctly for the purpose it has been implemented. The problem starts with the first step of designing such an architecture. Above code is not a whole problem solution. It is just a solution to a partial part of a program as the question requested. It's better to have a logical level of complexity when suggesting a solution to a question :) And also we are not writing code in a class to add a pure classic one for our students.

Comment: Instead of `Integer.valueOf(empNo).hashCode()` you can use `Integer.hash(empNo)`, though both constructs will just evaluate to `empNo`. But you can simply use `return Objects.hash(empNo, empName);` Besides that, a broken `equals` method is not “a solution to a partial part of a program”, it’s just broken. Especially, when nothing in the answer indicates that this code is incomplete. What’s so hard inserting the usual `if(obj == this) return true; if(!(obj instanceof Object2)) return false;` at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

just use `Stream::anyMatch` method

```
boolean result = list1.stream()
            .anyMatch(o1 -> list2.stream()
                    .anyMatch(o2 -> o1.getEmpno() == o2.getEmpno()
                            && o1.getEmpname().equals(o2.getEmpname())));
```