# Trying to create a 2 dimensional array from two existing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am very new to java and I am currently trying to recreate some python code in java. This is my problem:

I have 2 different variables:

```
    ArrayList <Double> x_loc= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <Double> y_loc= new ArrayList<>();
```

They both represent coordinates. My goal is to now create a 2-dimensional array with both of them so I could have something like array([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]).

I've thought about creating a new ArrayList and then adding each individual item:

```
ArrayList<Double[]> data_fin = new ArrayList<>(); 
data_fin.add(x_loc)
```

However, this doesn't work. I know I'm probably doing something very stupid but, as a newbie, I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create a class that holds two coordinate values?

Comment: I would suggest using `double[]` over `Double[]`. I think creating a new class is better solution though.

Comment: Or you can use the `zip` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists

Comment: You could also use a double list like List<List<Double>> this creates a two dimensional list and you won't have the complexity of index matching between the two separated arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the original `List`s in order to populate the combined `List`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x_loc.size() && i < y_loc.size(); i++) {
    data_fin.add (new Double[]{x_loc.get(i),y_loc.get(i)});
}
```

It can also be done with `Stream`s:

```
List<Double[]> data_fin = IntStream.range(0,x_loc.size())
                                   .mapToObj(i -> new Double[] {x_loc.get(i),y_loc.get(i)})
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Here I assumed both input `List`s have the same size).