# How to enumerate (add indices) to a List-like collection in Java

Tags: java, enumerate

Note: I am *not* referring to the java `enum`/`enumeration` but rather how to associate the ordinal/index of each element in a collection with the element.   I am looking for the equivalent of :

*scala* :

```
(1 to 10).zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (obj,i) =>  println(s"Obj[$i]=$obj") }obj.length}
```

*python* :

```
for i,obj in enumerate(range(1,11)):   
   print(f"obj[{i}]={str(obj)}")
```

*javascript* :

```
var myList= [...Array(10)].map((_,i) => 1+i)
myList.forEach( (obj,i) => console.log(`obj[${i}]=${obj}`))
```

It does not appear that java has a perfect/simple analog?  Do we need to use the somewhat awkward manual `zip` of lists like in this question? [How to zip two Java Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists) ?   What might be the most concise way to associate indices with the list elements?

Comment: Lists elements do have indices.  I feel like you're asking something more than that, but I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong  Lists do have indices but I mentioned `Collections` in an attempt to indicate any iterable container including ones not providing indices.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  AFAIK there's no easy way to do that in Java.  If it were me I would just start off with an IntStream and index into the collection from there, as the duplicate targets suggest.  Interesting concept, though, as a Java programmer I've never heard of "zipping" collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List may be converted into a map with indexes as keys like this:

```java
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> list.get(i)));
```

If `Map` is not needed, Stream API provides [`IntStream::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) method:

```java
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + " -> " + list.get(i)));
```

Also it is possible to use [`Iterable::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and count the index separately (e.g. with `AtomicInteger`):

```java
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(index.getAndIncrement() + " -> " + x));
```

Comment: Presuming we want a `forEach` on the `(index, element)` tuple than what is the most concise version? Your `Map` has its uses but is partially extraneous for that purpose given we do not care /need to retain any `Map` afterwards.

Comment: (after your update): Yes that's what I am looking for