# zip method in java

Tags: python, java

Is there any equivalent of zip method from pyton in java?

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")

x = zip(a, b)
```

(('John', 'Jenny'), ('Charles', 'Christy'), ('Mike', 'Monica'))

Comment: There's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists

Comment: If they are always of same length, the simplest and most efficient would be creating the object you need with a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution with IntStream

```
List<String> names1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("John", "Charles", "Mike", "Dennis"));
List<String> names2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica"));
IntStream
  .range(0, Math.min(names1.size(), names2.size()))
  .mapToObj(i -> names1.get(i) + ":" + names2.get(i))
  .toList();
```

But better looks solution with JOOL library

```
Seq
  .of("John","Charles", "Mike")
  .zip(Seq.of("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Guava library has a [`Streams.zip(Stream, Stream, BiFunction)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method, which provides the same functionality as Python's `zip` function using the Stream API.

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/9a32e48c55e1e5304507c88344ea22d7e5ed839a/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java#L343-L373) if you're curious:

```java
  public static <A extends @Nullable Object, B extends @Nullable Object, R extends @Nullable Object>
      Stream<R> zip(
          Stream<A> streamA, Stream<B> streamB, BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, R> function) {
    checkNotNull(streamA);
    checkNotNull(streamB);
    checkNotNull(function);
    boolean isParallel = streamA.isParallel() || streamB.isParallel(); // same as Stream.concat
    Spliterator<A> splitrA = streamA.spliterator();
    Spliterator<B> splitrB = streamB.spliterator();
    int characteristics =
        splitrA.characteristics()
            & splitrB.characteristics()
            & (Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.ORDERED);
    Iterator<A> itrA = Spliterators.iterator(splitrA);
    Iterator<B> itrB = Spliterators.iterator(splitrB);
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            new AbstractSpliterator<R>(
                min(splitrA.estimateSize(), splitrB.estimateSize()), characteristics) {
              @Override
              public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super R> action) {
                if (itrA.hasNext() && itrB.hasNext()) {
                  action.accept(function.apply(itrA.next(), itrB.next()));
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
            },
            isParallel)
        .onClose(streamA::close)
        .onClose(streamB::close);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you'll have to create a map by looping the lists:

```
public Map<String, String> zip(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    var map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (var i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        map.put(a.get(i), b.size() <= i ? b.get(i) : null);
    }
    
    return map;
}
```

Comment: A map cannot contain duplicate keys, it is not a suitable substitute except in special cases for `zip`, Indeed, in Python, `zip` is an iterator, so this would usually defeat the point anyway