# Combine lists of 2 different objects into list of single object using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists as below:

List ids = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List reps = Arrays.asList("abc","pqr","xyz");

Now I want to create list of Prediction objects with values mapped from above two lists in sequence like below:

List results = [ Prediction(1,"abc") , Prediction(2,"pqr"), Prediction(3,"xyz") ]

```
class Prediction {
    int id;
    String rep;
}
```

How this can be done using Java8 Stream API.

Comment: Can you share your code-attempt, and also describe the issue that you've faced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zip two Java Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963297/how-to-zip-two-java-lists)

Comment: How about writing `List<Prediction> results = Arrays.asList(new Prediction(1,"abc") , new Prediction(2,"pqr"), new Prediction(3,"xyz"));` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you described is called [zipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipping_(computer_science)).

If you are sure the lists are evenly of length, you could do something like:

```
IntStream.range(0, ids.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Prediction(ids.get(i), reps.get(i)))
    .toList()
```

*Assuming the Prediction class has a constructor like that...*